# Custom Theme Repository update

Tags: 8, theming, composer

I have a custom theme that I use in several websites.

My theme is on gitlab.

I can download my theme by composer in different websites.

My problem is when I update repository theme with a fix or new feature and then this do not mirror on websites, even if I delete theme folder and composer.json info, it's always stuck on the same version.

My composer.json of theme repository

```
{
"name": "test/test-theme",
"description": "Drupal Custom Theme",
"type": "drupal-custom-theme",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {}
```

}

My composer.json from the website:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
          "name": "test/test-theme",
          "version": "dev",
          "type": "drupal-custom-theme",
          "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "{URL}",
            "reference": "master"
          }
        }
      }
],
"require": {
    "test/test-theme": "dev",
 }
```

How can I update my theme last features with composer?

Comment: miststudent2011's answer is the right way to solve it long term, in the short you might get away with changing the require to `"test/test-theme": "dev-master"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a similar setup. But the only difference is we create a new tag for every update in the theme repository. So we just reference the new tag in  website composer.I would suggest you to try that instead of referencing branch so you get updated code on every compiser update.

If you are not interested in doing in that manner I would suggest you to clear composer cache and execute `composer update` you will probably get the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked :)
I had another question, it is possible to have same logic as a contrib theme/module? So I just need to run "composer update" and always get last update without reference a new tag?
Another question, I have changed a JS file content in my website (delete couple of lines), then run again "composer update" without changing tag reference, but my file didn't go to it's original state (theme repository state), is that normal to happen? Is there a way to force always get to original state?

Comment: It is recommended to delete vendor and contrib themes and modules directories before composer install or update. By this way you get clean packages if any packages were corrupted earlier.Yes, you can get latest code by referencing branch as dev-master as suggested by @Clive in the above comment.